# Form component name is updating in antd in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-redux, antd

I am using antd form to create a list of task, each form has "submit" and "cancel" button, Whenever the user creates a task, generates a new form. I kept the number of tasks count as form id. But while on changing the fields, I have to get the form Id, but the form Id is updating with the task count value.

Create Task.js

```
import React from "react";
import actions from "../redux/actions";
import store from "../redux/store";
import { Button } from 'antd';
import '../stylesheet/createTask.scss';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import TaskForm from "./taskForm";
const CreateTask=()=>{
    const addTask=useSelector((state)=>{
        const {taskCount,task,templates}=state?.reducers
        return {taskCount,task,templates}
    })
    const {taskCount,task,templates}=addTask;
    const createTask=()=>{
        templates.push(<div id={`task${taskCount+1}`} key={`template${taskCount}`}><TaskForm/></div>);
        store.dispatch({type:actions.ON_ADD_TASK,payload:templates})
    }
return(
    <div className={"create-task"}>
        <span className={"task-count"}>Task {taskCount} </span>
        <Button onClick={createTask}>+</Button>
        {templates && templates.map((data)=>data)}
    </div>
)
}
export default CreateTask;
```

TaskForm.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button, Select,TimePicker,DatePicker, Space } from 'antd';
import moment from 'moment';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import actions from "../redux/actions";
import store from "../redux/store";
import tasks from "../redux/reducers";


const layout = {
    labelCol: {
        span: 8,
    },
    wrapperCol: {
        span: 16,
    },
};
const tailLayout = {
    wrapperCol: {
        offset: 8,
        span: 16,
    },
};

const TaskForm = () => {
    const [form] = Form.useForm();
    const taskDetails=useSelector((state)=>{
        const {taskCount,task}=state?.reducers
        return {taskCount,task}
    })
    const [fields, setFields] = useState([
        { userData: {
            task_msg:"",
            assigned_user:"",
            task_date: moment('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
            task_time:moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss'),
            time_zone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
            is_completed: 0,
        }},
    ])
    const userData = {

    };

    const{taskCount,task}=taskDetails;

    const onFinish = (fieldsValue) => {
        const values = {
            ...fieldsValue,
            'task_date': fieldsValue['task_date'].format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            'task_time': fieldsValue['task_time'].format('HH:mm:ss'),
        };
    store.dispatch({type:actions.ON_SAVE_TASK,payload:values})
    };

    function onTimeChange(time, timeString) {
        console.log(time, timeString);
    }

    function onDateChange(date, dateString) {
        console.log(date, dateString);
    }
    const fieldsChange=(newFields)=>{
        let id=newFields.target.id.split("_")[0].split("form")[1];
        console.log("id", id);
        console.log("new Fields", newFields.target.id)
        setFields(newFields)
        console.log("on field change" )
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("task Did update", task)
        // setFields(tasks)
    },[])

    return (
        <Form {...layout} form={form}
              initialValues={userData}
              name={`form${taskCount}`}
              onChange={fieldsChange}
              onFinish={onFinish}>
            <Form.Item
                label="Task Description"
                name={"task_msg"}
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
                label="Task Description"
                name="task_date"
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Space direction="vertical">
                    <DatePicker  onChange={onDateChange} defaultValue={ moment('2015-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')}  />
                </Space>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
                label="Task Description"
                name={"task_time"}
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                    },
                ]}
                >
                <Space direction="vertical">
                <TimePicker  onChange={onTimeChange} defaultValue={moment('00:00:00', 'HH:mm:ss')} />
                </Space>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item
                name="assigned_user"
                label="Assigned User"
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Input />
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
            <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
                <Button type="secondary" htmlType={"button"} >
                    Cancel
                </Button>
            </Form.Item>
        </Form>
    );
};

export default TaskForm;
```

Reducers.js:

```
import actions from "./actions";
const stateInit={
taskCount:0,
task:[],
userData:{
    task_msg: '',
    task_date: '',
    task_time: 36000,
    assigned_user: '',
    time_zone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
    is_completed: 0,
},
    templates:[],
};
export default function tasks(state=stateInit, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case actions.ON_ADD_TASK:{
            return {...state,
                taskCount: state.taskCount+1,
                task:[...state.task,{userData:{...state.userData}}],
                templates:action.payload,
               };
        }
        case actions.ON_SAVE_TASK:{
            return {
                ...state,
                task:[]
            }
        }
        default:{
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Form id is updating with the task count. Refer Image:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use props to have differnt form ids for each task.
In Task.js change createTask like this:

```
const createTask=()=>{
templates.push(<div id={`task${taskCount+1}`} key= 
{`template${taskCount}`}><TaskForm taskId={taskCount}/></div>);
    store.dispatch({type:actions.ON_ADD_TASK,payload:templates})
}
```

Then in TaskForm.js change your Form like this:

```
return (
    <Form {...layout} form={form}
          initialValues={userData}
          name={`form${props.taskId}`}
          onChange={fieldsChange}
          onFinish={onFinish}>
....
</Form>
```

Comment: Yeah, I too found this. Thanks!